# Make off-canvas menu starting from bottom bar in Foundation?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation-5

I'm using [Foundation's off-canvas menu](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/offcanvas.html)  along with a bottom bar that I've created where the `Menu` button is located on the bottom right of my fixed bottom bar. However, the off-canvas menu comes out from the top right of my page. Is there a way to have the off canvas menu to slide starting from the bottom right instead?

Thanks!